# Jquery Parallax Effect

Tags: jquery

I've been looking at many many many paralax tutorials, there's been way too much complication for what I actually need to achieve, and I'm sure there's some tricky yet easier way without plugins to do it.

Basically, All i want to do is have for example..

A rocket ship. On a space background. And when the user scrolls down, the rocket ship would scroll at say double or half the speed of the scroll. in x or y? Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Broadly speaking, you need to tie the rocket's ship's [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) to the document's [`.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/). For instance, you might set it so that its top position equals the document height minus the scrollTop, which would make it fly from the bottom to the top as the page scrolls.

Comment: As a demo, I hereby present "the world's laziest parallax effect:" http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/uBvpH/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. I've got lots of ideas. This doesn't sound overly complicated.

Create a variable outside of the scope of the function. give it a name like `last_position`, give it a value of `0`.

```
var last_position = 0;
```

Now capture the scroll event.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

});
```

Now, capture the distance we travel from the top on scroll. Save this variable into the last_position variable, and create an if statement.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var winTop = $(this).scrollTop(); 
  if(winTop > last_position){
    //we're scrolling down
  }else{
    //we're scrolling up
  }
  //update last_position here
  last_position = winTop;
});
```

No, within those if statements, use `.animate()` to set the `top & left` distances respectively. Calculate with whatever math you'd like to achieve your desired effect. It's important to note you'll want to `.stop()` each animation before you call it again. If you don't...well, you'll see why..

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var winTop = $(this).scrollTop(); 
  if(winTop > last_position){
    $('#spaceship').stop(true).animate({
      top: "+=15px",
      left: "-=15px"
    });
  }else{
    $('#spaceship').stop(true).animate({
      top: "-=15px",
      left: "+=15px"
    });
  }
  //update last_position here
  last_position = winTop;
});
```

Try it out yourself.

Comment: Thankyou! It does work perfectly! I just now have to position my objects in a parent because the offsets change it's absolute positioning, but other than that, it looks great :)

Comment: Hi @Ohgodwhy, 
Just wondering, is it possible to have to same effect, but on a background image position? 

For example, I have a div spanning the whole width of the page with a repeated cloud pattern, and i don't want to move the whole div, but move the postition of the cloud so It still repeats no matter when or where the user has scrolled?

Comment: @user1560537 I would position that div with ` position :fixed ` giev it a height/width of 100%, and then use one of the cross-browser backgroundPosition animate plugins...I'll put together a nice jsFiddle for you, because...I'm a nice guy. :p

Comment: @user1560537 [Here's the fullscreen version](http://jsfiddle.net/BnJ3G/embedded/result/) --- and --- [here's the non-minified version with all the working code.](http://jsfiddle.net/BnJ3G/)